# Trying To Get A Barcode Scanner Working With Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, ascii, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to make my barcode scanner work with my Arduino Mega (I'm using the Honeywell Eclipse 5145)
Despite the help I've received from my other two questions I still can't seem to get it working fully.

I have the Barcode Scanner sending the barcode number into the Serial Monitor properly but I've tried to add an If Statement to the variable so that

`If ([Placeholder]==(char)ascii {
digitalWrite(22, HIGH); 
delay(1000);

digitalWrite(22, LOW); 
}`

But this doesn't work. I've been told that the function ***ascii*** only stores one character at a time so it would output the characters one by one and not in one string. I've been trying to solve this for a while now but can't seem to get it to work. Also I don't know whereabouts i should put the code in my project.

Here's my current code,

```
#include <usbhid.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#include <hiduniversal.h>
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <SPI.h>
char scan;
//Barcodes
char Barcode1[] = {'7','6','2','2','2','1','0','4','1','1','0','0','6','\0'};
char Barcode2[] = {"8717644012208 "};

class MyParser : public HIDReportParser {
  public:
    MyParser();
    void Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf);
  protected:
    uint8_t KeyToAscii(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnScanFinished();
};

MyParser::MyParser() {}

void MyParser::Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf) {
  if (buf[2] == 1 || buf[2] == 0) return;

  for (uint8_t i = 7; i >= 2; i--) {
    if (buf[i] == 0) continue;

    if (buf[i] == UHS_HID_BOOT_KEY_ENTER) {
      OnScanFinished();
    }

    else {
      OnKeyScanned(i > 2, buf, buf[i]);
    }

    return;
  }
}

uint8_t MyParser::KeyToAscii(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  if (VALUE_WITHIN(key, 0x04, 0x1d)) {
    if (upper) return (key - 4 + 'A');
    else return (key - 4 + 'a');
  }

  else if (VALUE_WITHIN(key, 0x1e, 0x27)) {
    return ((key == UHS_HID_BOOT_KEY_ZERO) ? '0' : key - 0x1e + '1');
  }

  return 0;
}

void MyParser::OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  uint8_t ascii = KeyToAscii(upper, mod, key);
  Serial.print((char)ascii);
  scan = (char)ascii;

}


void MyParser::OnScanFinished() {

  Serial.println(" - Finished");

}

USB          Usb;
USBHub       Hub(&Usb);
HIDUniversal Hid(&Usb);
MyParser     Parser;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
  Serial.println("Start");

  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.println("OSC did not start.");
  }

  delay( 200 );

  Hid.SetReportParser(0, &Parser);
}

void loop() {

  Usb.Task();
}
```

I think I somehow need to have a variable that stores the data when all the characters are received from the function ***ascii*** and then use that variable in the If Statement instead of `(char)ascii`. If you have any questions please comment below and I'll try my best to answer (I'm not that familiar with `ascii`)

Please provide example if possible

Thanks,

Comment: There is no function **ascii**. You define a variable of type `uint8_t`, which you could get rid of, if your function `KeyToAscii`would return a `char` right away. (Just by declaring it as `char`, no other change required.

Comment: @datafiddler Would you be able to give a rough example. I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Please, consider that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are integral types in C++. Hence, they can be used with the same operations like any other integral type. That holds also for character constants: `'A'` is nothing else than another form of an integral constant of value 65 (with type `char`) if the compiler/platform uses ASCII encoding. `std::uint8_t` is very probably nothing else than something like `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`. So, a value of type `std::uint8_t` can be converted into a value of `char` just by making a type cast (and vice versa).

Comment: the comments and the answer focus on unimportant type conversion. OP wants  to put the string sent by the scanner in a string variable. I am sure the code was not written by the OP. it is some example. there is no attempt to collect the received characters. I would recommend a codding course

Comment: @Juraj you're right. Same applies to the question itself. Probably the usual confusion between char and char*. And comparing `char*`s using `==` does not do what OP expects. -> `strcmp`

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyParser : public HIDReportParser {
  public:
    MyParser();
    void Parse(USBHID *hid, bool is_rpt_id, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf);
  protected:
    char KeyToAscii(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnScanFinished();
};

 char MyParser::KeyToAscii(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  if (VALUE_WITHIN(key, 0x04, 0x1d)) {
    if (upper) return (key - 4 + 'A');
    else return (key - 4 + 'a');
  }
  else if (VALUE_WITHIN(key, 0x1e, 0x27)) {
    return ((key == UHS_HID_BOOT_KEY_ZERO) ? '0' : key - 0x1e + '1');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This allows

```
void MyParser::OnKeyScanned(bool upper, uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  scan = KeyToAscii(upper, mod, key);
  Serial.print(scan);
}
```

which gives a sample to Scheff's and my comments.
Your question resp. your problem with comparing characters and setting Arduino outputs is not yet clear to me.

Comment: I ran into an error. `prototype for 'char MyParser::KeyToAscii(bool, uint8_t, uint8_t)' does not match any in class 'MyParser'` Basically what I'm trying to do is have different LEDs lighting up depending on what barcode I scan

Comment: You didn't adapt the class definition. See my now extended sample. BTW: I don't care and assume your `VALUE_WITHIN` and everything with USB and /or HID in the name is defined somewhere.